# CSS preprocessor that supports querying

Tags: css, less

I need the following functionality:

```
/* define rule */
div.primary { padding: 12px 0 0 0; }

/* use it */
div.secondary { @(div.primary, padding-top) }
/* or */
div.secondary { padding-top: @(div.primary).padding-top }
```

It looks like lesscss does not support such queries. Maybe extending it would be a best way? Then how to extend it?

**Update:** I've found that the less' author had decided to drop this feature: https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

You have to be more indirect. Define a variable and use that, like so:

```
@topPad: 12px;

/* use it to define rule */ 
div.primary { padding: @topPad 0 0 0; } 

/* use it again */ 
div.secondary { padding-top: @topPad;}
```

Comment: I know what lesscss can do and interested in what it cannot.

Comment: @AlexAtNet--Sorry. One never knows for sure on this site what people know or don't know. It looked to me like you were just needing to do something variables were designed for.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this, but you may be able to use LessCSS's built in javascript parsing to get what you need.

```
div.secondary{
   padding-top: `((document.createElement('div')).className='primary').style.paddingTop`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is close to what I want to achieve but I cannot use this solution because files are processed with nodejs.